# Query for unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following database table in Access:

```
Field1 | Field2
A | 1
B | 1
C | 2
D | 2
B | 3
O | 3
L | 3
```

I want to develop a query in Access (preferably without using SQL) to select all values in Field2 corresponding to an occurence of the value "B" in field 1. This query should yield

```
Field1|Field2
A | 1
B | 1
B | 3
O | 3
L | 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.field2 in (select t2.field2 from t as t2 where t2.field1 = 'B');
```